# couchbase cbimport key generation with key in nest json

Tags: full-text-search, couchbase

I have the following json document to be uploaded to a full text search index

```
{
    "bank_id": {
        "country_code": "AT",
        "bank_code": "ASPKAT2LXXX",
        "bank_code_type": "SWIFT_CODE"
    },
    "institution": {
        "name": "Allgemeine Sparkasse Oberoesterreich Bankaktiengesellschaft"
    },
    "address": {
        "address_line_1": "Promenade 11-13",
        "address_line_2": "Linz",
        "country_code": "AT"
    },
    "bank_capabilities": ["INSTANT_CREDIT"],
    "payment_network_details": [{
        "network": "REAL_TIME_PAYMENTS",
        "capabilities": ["INSTANT_CREDIT"]
    }]
}
```

And I want to generate key with `country_code` and `bank_code`. How can i accomplish this?
tried with `-g  %bank_id.country_code%::%bank_id.bank_code%` and it is not working.

Comment: when you say it's 'not working', what is happening instead? error message?